# How to load CSS on specific section on Shopify Themes?

Tags: html, css, shopify, themes

I am trying to create another section and apply a CSS that is in assets folder. But when I put the `{{ 'style-section-block.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}` to the page that I want to apply the CSS to, it affects the other sections as well even though I only put in the section that I want to change.

I am expecting to be able to edit one section page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply CSS specific section, first you add a unique class or ID to the section you want to style. After use that unique class or ID in CSS file you can style section. Example is

```
<div class="my-section">
  <!-- section content -->
</div>
```

"my-section" is the unique class name of the this section. You can use that class name add style to section.

```
.my-section {
      font-size: 24px;      
    }
```

According to shopify themes. You can conditionally use the CSS file based on the current page handle or page template. According my thinking you can do this 'template' or 'page.handle' variable in your theme's 'layout' file. I mean 'theme.liquid' file. You can add below code into 'layout' file 'head' section.

```
{% if template contains 'your-specific-template' or page.handle == 'your-specific-page-handle' %}
  {{ 'style-section-block.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

Replace 'your-specific-template' with your template name or 'your-specific-page-handle' with your page handle name. And remove CSS link from the other sections.

Comment: Hi, what I mean is when I call the link of the CSS it will be load to that specific page only. Not to the whole themes. Because when I tried to call `{{ 'style-section-block.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}` to the page that I want it to effect. It also affect the other page when I only call it to the page that I want to effect.

Comment: You can conditionally use the CSS file based on the current  page handle or page template. According my thinking you can do this 'template' or 'page.handle' variable in your theme's 'layout' file. I mean 'theme.liquid' file.

Comment: I will update my code according to my idea.